# Cannot specify link libraries for target "curl-demo" which is not built by this project

Tags: c, curl, cmake, cmakelists-options

I started using CMake for my project, but now when I want to use libcurl, it doesn't work. Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(getter C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

add_executable(getter main.c brute.c brute.h)

target_link_libraries(curl-demo CURL::libcurl)
```

When I tried to run this, it said `Cannot specify link libraries for target "curl-demo" which is not built by this project.`

And I don't have any idea what that means...
I searched everywhere but couldn't find any cases like this. Can someone please help me??

Thanks!

Comment: `add_executable(getter` What target do you create? `target_link_libraries(curl-demo` What target comes here?

Comment: @273K just as I was saying i just started with that. I thought it's some type of command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm just stupid. `curl-demo` isn't supposed to be some kind of command - it's your project name. So when I start with `project(getter C)`, I have to use `target_link_libraries(getter CURL::libcurl)`!